# how to get URI as parameters in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

How can i get the URI and use it as params in nodejs. I am using express.

```
http://localhost:3000/getParams/param1/param2/param3/paramN
```

I want to get "/param1/param2/param3/paramN".

This is my current code:

```
app.get("/getParams/:params", test.params);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So does your current code work?  If not, what are the expected and actual results?

Comment: it doesn't work. it only get the 1st param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the full path as one param, or you can access each segment as a separate param.  To get as one param:

```
app.get('/mysvc/:input(*)', function(req, res) 
                            { 
                                console.log(req.params.input);
                                // ...
                            });
```

Notice the route which says everything (regex match of *) after /mysvc/ will be mapped to the input reques param.  Then you can reference it via req.params

In this example, a request to /mysvc/foo/bar will output foo/bar

If you want to get each segment as a separate param then:

```
    app.get('/mysvc/:param1/:param2'
```

access via req.params.param1, req.params.param2, etc...

Answer (score 3):

In express parameters are available in the `req` object `req.params.parameterName` so in your case you can access it within the route like this `req.params.params`.

The params that you can access from the handler depends upon the route definitions. If you route is like

```
/my/:one/:two/:three
```

then you can access them as

```
req.params.one
req.params.two
req.params.three
```